# Returning an empty array of posts when using mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to get a particular user's posts. It's returning me an empty array of posts. Here's my code. I think I have referenced everything correctly, there must be some mistake.

`User model`

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, reuired: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    posts:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

`Post model`

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
}, { timestamps: true }
```

`router.get("/posts/:id", usersController.getUserPosts)`

```js
    getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id, async (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" })
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).json({ error: "No user" })
            } else if (user) {
                user = await User.populate("user", {
                  path: "posts",
                  model: "Post"
              })
            return res.status(200).json({ user })
         }
      })
    }
```

Edit

The users in the database are:

`/users/list`

```js
{
    "users": [
        {
            "posts": [],
            "_id": "5e66496fcaf5d6697ca3fdbc",
            "username": "JimmyPage",
            "email": "jimmypage@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$mu0IcHADj5YVIT/66EEfPOxL3cvEjqDsnJUcrST8ZcatTOcQ42kn6",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "posts": [],
            "_id": "5e66499fcaf5d6697ca3fdbe",
            "username": "AxlRose",
            "email": "axlrose@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$H3X3efz02RonlvNXaRPr2eEbflSiFK1ITFdbyT2igUGDK9gDpIJqO",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:23.702Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:23.702Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The posts look like this:

`/posts/list`

```js
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "_id": "5e66498ccaf5d6697ca3fdbd",
            "title": "Jimmy Page's post",
            "description": "This is Jimmy Page's post",
            "user": {
                "posts": [],
                "_id": "5e66496fcaf5d6697ca3fdbc",
                "username": "JimmyPage",
                "email": "jimmypage@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2b$10$mu0IcHADj5YVIT/66EEfPOxL3cvEjqDsnJUcrST8ZcatTOcQ42kn6",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:04.840Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:04.840Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e6649b5caf5d6697ca3fdbf",
            "title": "Axl Rose's Post",
            "description": "This is Axl Rose's Post",
            "user": {
                "posts": [],
                "_id": "5e66499fcaf5d6697ca3fdbe",
                "username": "AxlRose",
                "email": "axlrose@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2b$10$H3X3efz02RonlvNXaRPr2eEbflSiFK1ITFdbyT2igUGDK9gDpIJqO",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:23.702Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:23.702Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:45.751Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:50:45.751Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e664b7bf120ab6c0d9999c9",
            "title": "Jimmy Page's second post",
            "description": "This is Jimmy Page's second post\n\n",
            "user": {
                "posts": [],
                "_id": "5e66496fcaf5d6697ca3fdbc",
                "username": "JimmyPage",
                "email": "jimmypage@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2b$10$mu0IcHADj5YVIT/66EEfPOxL3cvEjqDsnJUcrST8ZcatTOcQ42kn6",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-03-09T13:58:19.261Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-09T13:58:19.261Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I've added the above code in my question. I've been stuck in this like forever like I'm trying to show user's posts in his profile and also planning to show the global feed of all user's posts showing.

It will be great if you could help me out. I will really appreciate it. THANKS.

**List posts controller is like this:**

```js
listposts:  (req, res) => {
    Post.find({}, async (error, posts) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" })
        } else if (!posts) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: "sorry no posts" })
        } else if (posts) {
            posts = await Post.populate(posts, {
              path: 'user',
              model: 'User'
            });
            return res.status(200).json({ posts })
        }
    })
}
```

The users document:

```js
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5e66496fcaf5d6697ca3fdbc"),
      "posts" : [ ],
      "username" : "JimmyPage",
      "email" : "jimmypage@gmail.com",
      "password" : "$2b$10$mu0IcHADj5YVIT/66EEfPOxL3cvEjqDsnJUcrST8ZcatTOcQ42kn6",
      "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z"),
      "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:49:35.834Z"), "__v" : 0 
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e66499fcaf5d6697ca3fdbe"),
     "posts" : [ ],
     "username" : "AxlRose",
     "email" : "axlrose@gmail.com",
     "password" : "$2b$10$H3X3efz02RonlvNXaRPr2eEbflSiFK1ITFdbyT2igUGDK9gDpIJqO",
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:50:23.702Z"),
     "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:50:23.702Z"),
     "__v" : 0 
}
```

And the posts document:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e66498ccaf5d6697ca3fdbd"),
    "title" : "Jimmy Page's post",
    "description" : "This is Jimmy Page's post",
    "user" : ObjectId("5e66496fcaf5d6697ca3fdbc"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:50:04.840Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:50:04.840Z"),
    "__v" : 0 
}


{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5e6649b5caf5d6697ca3fdbf"),
     "title" : "Axl Rose's Post",
     "description" : "This is Axl Rose's Post",
     "user" : ObjectId("5e66499fcaf5d6697ca3fdbe"),
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:50:45.751Z"),
     "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:50:45.751Z"),
     "__v" : 0 }


{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5e664b7bf120ab6c0d9999c9"),
     "title" : "Jimmy Page's second post",
     "description" : "This is Jimmy Page's second post\n\n",
     "user" : ObjectId("5e66496fcaf5d6697ca3fdbc"),
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:58:19.261Z"),
     "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-09T13:58:19.261Z"), 
     "__v" : 0 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the user info and his/her posts.

```js
getUserPosts: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).populate("posts");

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No user" });
    }

    return res.status(200).json({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
  }
};
```

Comment: still empty posts im getting..do i have to add post id somewhere. i read in some of the other answers but i couldn't figure out how to get the post id here.

Comment: @ubuntu7788 how do you create model for posts collection? It must be something like this `mongoose.model("Posts", postSchema )`.  The Posts here must match Posts here `ref: "Posts" `

Comment: my mongoose model is **export const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema, "posts")**. I don't know why that third parameter **"posts"** is needed. It's optional, right?

Comment: @ubuntu7788 you need to change your ref like this `posts:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]` in the user schema.  We are not interested that 3rd parameter.

Comment: But I've given ```posts:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]``` in `User` model, and ```user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }``` in `Post` model. –

Comment: @ubuntu7788 yes that's correct. But in the question ref was 'Posts' not 'Post'

Comment: But I'm still getting the user object with an empty array of posts. Though I have made two posts by this user in the database. I'm doing it in postman with a ```GET``` request to ```/posts/:id```. The ```is``` here is the user id.

Comment: @ubuntu7788 can you add user and posts documents to your question?

Comment: @ubuntu7788 I actually wanted to see the documents in the users and posts collections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209865/discussion-between-ubuntu7788-and-suleymansah).

Comment: can you look into this?

Comment: @ubuntu7788 now this populate will work since you now can push the created post id to the user.posts

Comment: @ubuntu7788 you are welcome, can you please mark this as answer and upvote?