# Why am I not able to populate the posts field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So, as you could see from my previous questions, I've been stuck in `populate` of mongoose. I have two models, `User` and `Post`, and currently, I'm trying to get a single user's posts but not able to do it.

```js
getUserPosts: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).populate("posts");

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No user" });  
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ userposts: user.posts });

    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
    }
}
```

The problem is I'm somehow getting an empty array of posts. If I manually push the posts documents post id, then it's working, otherwise it's not.

Comment: do you have ref for post model in user model?

Comment: yes i have `posts:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]`. Also, check my previous question. It has all the details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606546/returning-an-empty-array-of-posts-when-using-mongoose-populate

Comment: can you try populate("post") and/or populate("postss")? Sometimes mongoose can try pluralize the field even if its given as plural.

Comment: no, doesn't work.